Is this seqlock implementation correct from the c++ memory model point of view?
I red this article Can Seqlocks Get Along With Programming Language Memory Models?
And found that one of the example (figure 6) is not correct from the c++ memory model point of view .
atomic<unsigned> seq; // seqlock representation
// assume big enough to ignore overflow
atomic<int> data1, data2; // protected by seq

T reader() {
    int r1, r2;
    unsigned seq0, seq1;
    do {
        seq0 = seq.load(m_o_acquire);
        r1 = data1.load(m_o_relaxed);
        r2 = data2.load(m_o_relaxed);
        atomic_thread_fence(m_o_acquire);
        seq1 = seq.load(m_o_relaxed);
    } while (seq0 != seq1 || seq0 & 1);
    // do something with r1 and r2;
}

void writer(...) {
    unsigned seq0 = seq;
    while (seq0 & 1 ||
           !seq.compare_exchange_weak(seq0, seq0+1)) {}
    data1 = ...;
    data2 = ...;
    seq = seq0 + 2;
}

Figure 6. Seqlock reader with acquire fence

Here it is assumed that at the time of reading seq0 there was synchronize with the reader and the "last" writer, but the memory model does not guarantee this. To do this, we must force synchronize with an RMW operation (e.g. seq.fetch_add(0) or seq.cas(seq0, seq0)) when reading seq1 and if seq1 == seq0, therefore at the time of reading seq0 there was synchronize with with "last" writer => happens before

Can you show us the code for the writer?  A full analysis needs to take it into account.

Cppref memory order

Synchronizes with


If an atomic store in thread A is a release operation, an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is an acquire operation, and the load in thread B reads a value written by the store in thread A, then the store in thread A synchronizes-with the load in thread B.

Reading seq0 with an acquire order is enough to establish a synchronizes with relationship with the writer,  you don't need an RMW here, you either read an old value which will make the whole operation fail and retried or you read the new value which will establish the synchronizes with relationship, there is no third option.
If you read the old value for seq0 and read new data then the fence will force seq1 to be the new value, which will fail the check, there is no scenario where seq0 == seq1 and the data is not the same one written before seq0
The main problem with seqlock is that writes can be reordered by the CPU which is why a C++ memory-model compliant implementation needs a compare-exchange on the writer side, which makes it not exactly a seqlock, but a slower modified version of it.
While the provided seqlock has no races, it can read any value for the data in the modification order, not necessarily the newest, doing an RMW to have this guarantee would make it an order of magnitude slower because of cache ping-ponging.

"Reading seq0 with an acquire order is enough to establish a synchronizes with relationship with the writer"
It's not enough because as you mention cpp reference says: "and the load in thread B reads a value written by the store in thread A"

@Alex which part exactly do you think is not satisfied ? Again, if you read a different value, then the loop will repeat because seq0 != seq1 , but if you read the value written by the other thread then you are synchronized, under no scenario can you read a different value and still pass the check.

Just read seq0 it's not enough to establish synchronizes with  you also need "and the load in thread B reads a value written by the store in thread A". To ensure synchronizes with happens, you need to read the latest value in modification order, and it's only possible with RMW.

@Alex under this condition seq1 will then read a different value due to the fence, and the loop must repeat, it doesn't matter whether we were synchronized or not when reading the data in that loop, it cannot succeed

@Alex if you read the new data then the fence will establish synchronzation before reading seq1, so seq1 will be at least as new as the data, which can never be equal to seq0 if seq0 wasn't the last value in the modification order.

Thread can read the same seq1 (seq0 == seq1) but seq, data1, data2 are already modified.

@Alex yes, but it doesn't matter. this lock doesn't force synchronization, it only forces that the data is read or written atomically, it doesn't stall the cpu waiting for new values.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Alex i don't think any implementation of seqlock ever provided the guarantee that data is newest, furthermore doing a RMW will pingpong the cache lines, making it as slow as a normal mutex or a futex.

It's not about newest it's about inconsistency. data1 and data2 can come from different writes and condition seq1 == seq2 still be satisfy.

@Alex the fence will make it so that seq1 is at least as new as the data that we just read or newer, if we read any new data then seq1 != seq0 , end of story, we are not necessarily synchronized with the last writer, but we are synchronized with the writer of the data that we just read.

@Alex Assune 3 writes 1,2,3 . If seq0 and the data and seq1 are synchronized with writer 1 then we succeed, but if seq0 is synchronized with writer 1 but the data came from writer 2 then seq1 must come from writer 2 or 3 which means we fail the check, and if seq0 came from writer 1 but part of the data came from 2 and part from 3 then it also doesn't matter whether we get seq1 from writer 2 or 3, in both cases the check fails, under no condition can the check pass unless seq0 is synchronized with the data.

Which part of the c++ memory model can guarantee this behavior?

@Alex it can because b store is relaxed, so it can happen before a, if b store was a release then the assert will never trigger, ie: the fence acquire needs a respective release on b, the load on b can still be relaxed, the synchronization is not on the load but on the fence.

Note that in your seqlock the data store is seq_cst which also acts like a release, you can read more about how the fences work https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence

Assert can fire in this example? https://pastebin.com/egxxKJFQ

According to cpp reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence.
An atomic release operation X in thread A synchronizes-with an acquire fence F in thread B, if: there exists an atomic read Y (with any memory order); Y reads the value written by X (or by the release sequence headed by X); Y is sequenced-before F in thread B;

@Alex no, it cannot fire, for the reason you have just mentioned, The release X on b synchronizes with the fence because there exists an atomic load Y on b, with any memory order.

Oh, now I'm understand. Thank you very much @Ahmed AEK!

Is an example from the question equivalent to this?https://pastebin.com/UVVrm8E9?

@Alex it is, the data is stored with a release (seq_cst store is a release + sequential consistency), the data is b, and the seq1 load is the load on a, the seq0 store is the store on a

And what about exchange acquire fence to data1.load(acquire), data2.load(acquire)?

@Alex it will work but that would slow things down because then the cpu can't reorder data loads, we want the cpu to reorder data loads so it can load it all at once instead of 1 at a time, we only care that seq1 is loaded after the data, so a fence is enough
